# page locator changed after winter 22 upgrade

Tags: page-layout, js, querylocator, winter22

I am seeing that page locator changed on create new record pages, possibly after `winter'22` Salesforce release. Can this be possible.

For example,

old locator was available as,

```
//div[contains(@class,'slds-combobox__form-element')]//input)[2]
```

which now has been changed to

```
//div[contains(@class,'slds-combobox__form-element')]//input
```

Answer (score 2):

It's absolutely possible. The exact element structure of Salesforce pages is not a committed API contract. In maintaining our [Robot Framework keyword library](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/stable/robot.html), we regularly find small changes to locators required in order to work in new Salesforce releases.

This is something you'll have to handle as a regular maintenance process.

Answer (score 2):

Starting in [Spring '19](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lc_dom_inspection_tests.htm&type=5&release=218), all the release notes started including this disclaimer that is also called out in [Winter '22](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_ui_testing.htm&type=5&release=234) that explains these things *could* change after a release

> The content and structure of HTML, CSS, and the DOM can change at any
> time and can’t be considered a stable API. Automated UI tests that use
> tools like Selenium WebDriver to reach into component internals
> require your ongoing maintenance

Comment: Thank you so much Kris. much much helpful.